# Prove that product of two coprime subgroups is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

If A and B are finite normal subgroups of a group G such that the order of A and order of B are relatively prime. Prove that $ab = ba$ for all $a \in A$, $b \in B$.

So far I have been able to show that $A \cap B$ = {$e$} and that $AB$ is a normal subgroup. I know that to show $ab = ba$ I need that $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$ but I'm not sure how to start. Any hints/suggestions would be great.

Comment: hint: Using what you you know about $A,B$ what do you know about $aba^{-1}$ and what does this tell you about $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.  Here is a hint.  You've already shown that $A \cap B = \{e\}$ so if you could show that  $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$ (and similarly that $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in B$), then that would be sufficient.  Clearly, $a \in A$.  Can you show that $bab^{-1} \in A$ too?